# Present Progressive or Simple Present

Tags: present-tense, present-continuous, present-simple

I have a question about using present tenses;
would it be said that:

> 1. Robots are being developed
> 2. Robots are developed

I would say it is present progressive because the process is not finished and robots might fail and need to be rebuilt...etc. Am I correct?

Comment: The question lacks context. But "Robots are developed" is a fragment sentence, it lacks a location (here/in China) or an agent (by humans/hand/scientist).

Comment: To me, "are being developed" suggests the action of developing them continues, it's a work in progress. "are developed" could mean the development is over. "These robots are/were/have been developed by CompanyX".

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer to your question may be dependent on what you would like to express by using different tenses.

If you want to say that a robot is assembled and is in its final form (either mechanically or technically), then you can say (as much as it expresses the result) that **Robots are developed**.

However, there is another alternative, which emphasises the incompletedness of the robots' development: **Robots are being developed**. This means that they are still under a certain type of construction and it will take a while to come up with the final product.